Getting "Bad IL format" when loading exe file
I'm trying to explore .NET 8.0 exe file. When I try to load it with Assembly.LoadFrom or Assembly.LoadFile I'm getting Bad IL format. The format of the file '<file_path>.exe' is invalid. But if I change <OutputType> from Exe to Library all works fine. Is it possible to open exe file as .NET assembly?

Which version of .NET are you trying to load it with?

@Charlieface both net8.0 or net8.0-windows.

Is it perhaps compiled for 32 or 64 bit rather than AnyCPU?

@Charlieface AnyCPU, and I've changed only OutputType in csproj and it starts working.
